# Turning date string into a inter

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

One column in my dataframe has dates in the following format: `9-Dec-21`, e.g.

[image]

How can I convert the above date into this format? `20211209`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['new_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```